# How to host Codeigniter application and Wordpress blog in the same server?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

How do I host a Codeigniter application and a Wordpress blog on the same server?

I have this webserver where I currently host my CI application. I now am developing a WP blog and wanted to use the same webserver.

My CI app is answering by, for example, `myapp.com`, and I'm buying the `myblog.com` to point to my WP blog.

I don't necessarily need WP to be part of CI as controller/views. I could just use some `.htaccess` configuration and set my root directory like this:

```
---root_directory
------ci_app
------wp_blog
```

I am very bad at understanding `.htaccess` rewriting rules.

Any ideas? What is your recommendation?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're asking? What did you try? If you have two apps 2 folders then put the htaccess with their specific rules in each of the folders. Then just use the RewriteBase in htaccess for each folder. e.g. `RewriteBase /ci_app/`

Comment: So have you actually tried configuring your Apache server and can't get it to work? Without you telling us what you've tried to do in configuring your web server, it's difficult to diagnose the problem, if there even is one.

Comment: this is the question. how can I do this? what is the best practice or best option? where do I install WP? inside de 'view' folder? I didn't try anything because I wanted to hear what you guys do to not simply waste my time with bad attempts